# Display Microsoft Access data in textboxes by selecting an item in a listbox

Tags: c#, database, listbox

I know how to connect to an access database and so on.

My question is, I want to select an item from a list box, and then it must search the access database for the item I selected and display all its contents in textboxes. For example:

In the listbox I have the following added:

Car 1
Car 2
Car 3
etc.

If I select Car 2, I want it to read the database and display all Car 2's properties in textboxes.  So for example, once I select it, it can display Horsepower in a specific textbox, max speed in a specific text box, year model in a specific text box etc.

Could anyone help me out with this?

Comment: The answer to this question depends *heavily* on what technology you're using to display the information. How you use the selected value to retrieve the desired properties, and how you bind those properties to the textboxes, will be different depending on whether you're using, for example, ASP.NET, WinForms, or WPF. Please specify. :)

Comment: To follow on @djacobson: I don't see this question as having anything at all to do with Access, since Access isn't involved (C# is the development environment), and the quesiton doesn't seem to involve anything with retrieving data from a Jet/ACE data store.

Comment: Removed ms-access tag. Hopefully eze will return and elaborate. :)

Comment: It also doesn't seem to have much to do with C#, other than that's the programming language he's using.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have 1 textbox per property that will change whenever you select something different from your listbox here is what I would do. It sounds like you are already populating your listbox with some category from your database, possibly CarType. I would use LINQ to run a query to populate the results within the given textbox.

```
var query = from record in myTable.AsEnumerable()
            where record.CarType == myListBox.SelectedValue
            select record;

foreach (var record in query)
{
    horsePower.Text = record.HorsePower;
    //and so on
}
```

It sounds like you are setting up a custom control for this. However, I would suggest using a Data Grid to do what you are trying to do, instead of Text Boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using data binding?

```
listBox.DataSource = dataTableCars;
listBox.DisplayMember = "car_name";
listBox.ValueMember = "car_id";

txtBox.DataBindings.Add("Text",dataTableCars,"car_name");
txtBox.DataBindings.Add("Text",dataTableCars,"car_driver_name");
```

etc.